# How can I view timestamps in my Chrome browser history (on Android)?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, search-history

For security reasons, I need to check exactly when I accessed some websites on my phone a few days ago. The activity is stored in my mobile Chrome's browser history, but apparently the timestamps cannot be viewed - just the dates.

I know the timestamp information is stored because when I sync with my desktop Chrome, the timestamps appear there. However, for everything but the current day, it only seems to sync explicitly typed addresses and not Google searches (unlike the mobile Chrome app's history which has both, but no timestamps). This is frustrating to no end.

I was hoping to be able to do this without rooting my phone, though installing third-party apps would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, if you go to [Google My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com), you will be able to see this information. You can use the filter and choose "Chrome" so that only your browser history is visible for convenience.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks! Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

This functionality is built-into Chrome. Just hover your mouse over a date, and the time stamp appears.

Comment: How do you hover with a mouse on a phone?  Neither a short nor a long press gives this information!!