# Need Chrome Android timestamp from history - wasn't synching so not in Activities but page does show in app history - doesn't show time

Tags: chrome-for-android

I need the timestamp of history from 3 days ago on the Google Chrome Android app. I need to prove the time I visited a parking website 3 days ago using Chrome on Android. I can see the page under history, but the timestamps are only displayed for today. Before that, there are no timestamps shown.

I can see on my iPhone that the iPhone Chrome app does show timestamps for history even many days ago and it's not limited to today.

I have seen [How can I view timestamps in my Chrome browser history (on Android)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220075). I was logged into my Chrome account on Android (Samsung Galaxy S22) but did not have sync on. I tried syncing on 24 hours ago, but it doesn't seem my old activity in the phone is showing on Google Activity and only has activity on my Android from the time I turned sync on unfortunately.

How do I get the timestamp of the history on my Chrome app for a site I visited 3 days ago? It's shocking that is easily shown in the iPhone Chrome app but not on Android.

Tried turning synch on, as well as exporting data from Google Takeout but didn't help. The history before synch was turned on doesn't seem to be in Google Activity/Takeout etc.